# Laravel, axios: The first login request to server returns strange data {two_factor: false} instead of Auth:id(). How to fix it?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex

I want make axios return a response of just logged in user's id. When I was using Laravel Fortify with blade.php files, everything was too simple. Fortify was doing redirect to home page automatically after the successful login. But when I started to use Laravel with vue js and vuex, I faced a problem.
When I send login request by axios.post I get a strange response like this [image]

only after the second same request I get what I need from the needed controller, where I set the redirect home value. See what I mean in below picture.

[image]

I found an information that the problem partly tied with App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php class

but I still don't know what to do.

Here's my axios code

```
 actions:
        {
            login(context,payload) {
                axios.post('/login', {
                        email: payload.email,
                        password: payload.password
                    }
                ).then(response => {
                    console.log(payload.email+" "+payload.password);
                    console.log(response.data);
                    if (response.status === 201) {
                        console.log('login')
                    } else {
                        //console.log(response.data)
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log('oops')
                });
            },

            logout() {
                axios.post('logout').then(response => {
                    if (response.status === 302 || 401) {
                        console.log('logout')
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log('oops')
                });
            },
        }
```

And the controller code part which must work when fortify redirects after the successful login.

```
class UsersProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Auth::id();
    }
}
```

In my case it redirects since the second login request.
At first one if the login values are not correct, for example, not correct password, then returns response status code 422. But if username and password are correct it returns that strange code which I showed above in first screenshot.

I want to know. How can I get the redirect from the first request or if it is somehow can't be done, then just get a status code, that login process went successful?

Comment: Make sure you have added FortifyServiceProvider to app config. Happened to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

You first request to login hits the LoginResponse class, which just returns a json object containing {two_factor: false} (because your request wants json)

```
class LoginResponse implements LoginResponseContract
{
    /**
     * Create an HTTP response that represents the object.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? response()->json(['two_factor' => false])
                    : redirect()->intended(Fortify::redirects('login'));
    }
}
```

When making your second request the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware prevents hitting your LoginResponse again because you're already logged in.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? response()->json(['two_factor' => false])
                    : redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It passes your request to your UserProfileController I'd guess. Hard to say, because you didn't show your login logic. You should probably have one endpoint that is solely responsible for your login. Then another api endpoint to fetch data such as your users id and not relying on redirects in your Vue app. If you're working on a SPA consider using Laravel Sanctum.

Comment: You gave me helpful information, but what about of solution options in fortify context, not sanctum?

Comment: Well that depends on what you're trying to do. I won't be writing your login logic but a simple solution would be to customize the login response in your FortifyServiceProvider. It's in the docs [Customizing Redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#customizing-authentication-redirects)

Comment: And just to be clear. You'll still be using Fortify when working with Sanctum.